# vwprintf error handling (errno shows 0)

Tags: c++

I'm getting a negative value returns from `vwprintf`, and my message is not printed.
The documentation says a negative return value means an error occurred, but I can find a way to find an error code or message (`errno` value is not changed).
How can I find the error?

my code:

```
void func(const wchar_t * fmt, ...) const
{
    // fmt is not empty
    errno = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int result = vwprintf(fmt, args); // result = -1

    if(result < 0)
    {
        int isError = ferror(stdout); //isError = 1
        int errorCode = errno; //errorCode = 0
    }
    printf("\n");
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: `va_args` requires a variadic function argument (the three dots `...` ), i.e. something like `void myfunction(char* fmt, ...)`, and `va_start` requires the last argument before the variadic one. In your code, `fmt` is a local variable, and I miss the variadic argument somewhere. Can you show it?

Comment: this line `int result = vwprintf(fmt, args);` is trying to print the `char *fmt` empty string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/vwprintf/

Comment: @StephanLechner, sorry for not being clear. I've just edited the code so it's my original code.

Comment: @PRDeving. sorry for not being clear. I've just edited the code so it's my original code. fmt is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce any error; I expect that there is something wrong with the arguments you pass to the function. See the following code, which works for me. Hope it somehow solves your problem:

```
void func(const wchar_t * fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int result = vwprintf(fmt, args); // result = 19
    va_end(args);
}

int main()  {
    func(L"%d:%d:%s\n",10,20,"Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10:20:Hello world!
```

Comment: Actually it works for me for ~3000 lines, and then it just stops working.